# What is the "systematic component of the model", in bivariate linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, terminology, bivariate

I need to discuss the **systematic component of the model** in bivariate linear regression, but what is it in the first place? I have never come across this terminology in our class textbooks.

Comment: See https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3861.

Comment: @Scortchi - and this is why I give some hints etc in the comments.  I see the "graybeards" of the subject leading.

Comment: "Bivariate linear regression" is potentially ambiguous. Do you mean (i) a single-x-single-y situation, (ii) a situation where $Y$ is a vector of length two, or (iii) a situation where there are two predictors (Y~X1+X2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many models for data can be conceived as having the form

$$E(Y|\,\underline{X}=\underline{x}\,\!) = \mu(\,\!\underline{x}\,\!)+\epsilon$$

where given $x$, $\mu(x)$ is fixed; this is called the *systematic component* of the data-generating process, while $\epsilon$ is the *random component*.

We're often interested in estimating $\mu$ (as a function of $x$) and some characteristics of $\epsilon$ (such as its variance).